# Is "nodding" always a conscious act?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

This is perfectly normal:

> He nodded at her in agreement.

How about this?

> He fell asleep in the bus. I watched him nod, his puffy hair brushing
>   the seat in front of him.

Is *nod* in this case inappropriate because it's an unconscious act? If so, what' s a more appropriate word?

**EDIT:**

When I typed in "I watched him nod" on Google, I only got results that refer to a "conscious" nod:

> Angie said, as she watched him nod at that [[...]](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=M5Rm3-X-YQsC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22watched%20him%20nod%22&source=bl&ots=WRf9jy0PPX&sig=-4QhnPo2H6lNsF_fEFZKf4XnDrg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIn6q4rJfWxwIVQxaUCh3tvw40)
>
> Ryan commented as he watched him nod to the other [[...]](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=AMNRCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT171&lpg=PT171&dq=%22watched%20him%20nod%22&source=bl&ots=fy_uGRUeuK&sig=ZNkb3WVnn5A3rZ-93FivwK2klqI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAmoVChMIn6q4rJfWxwIVQxaUCh3tvw40)

That's why I'm a little confused.

Comment: "Nod" is also a figurative way of saying "sleep."

Comment: The second type of *nod* is characteristic of someone *transitioning* from wakefulness to the first stage of sleep, so it's not fully conscious nor fully unconscious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To nod may also refer to an unconscious movement:

[To nod](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nod):

> - (intr) to let the head fall forward through drowsiness; be almost asleep: *the old lady sat nodding by the fire.* (Collins)

Comment: This is thus general reference. AHDEL adds the non-sentient-at-any-time agentive usage: 4. To sway, move up and down, or droop, as flowers in the wind.

Answer (score 1):

More commonly:

He fell asleep in the bus. I watched him **nod off**, his puffy hair brushing the seat in front of him.

Using *nod off* eliminates any confusion with the other sort of nodding.